# Illegal property declarations

Tags: c#, properties

I've been trying to figure out which of these is illegal:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set;}

public int MyProperty { get; protected set; }

public int MyProperty { get; }

public int MyProperty { get{ return 0; } }

public int MyProperty { get { return 0; } set { ; } }
```

None of them returns an error for me but one of them is supposed to be illegal. Can someone tell me which one and why?

Comment: could you please add what C# version your question refers to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# 6.0 *all* are legal, in prior versions

```
   public int MyProperty { get; }
```

is *illegal* - you can't assign (i.e. `set`) the returned value. In *C# 6.0*, however, you can either put

```
  public int MyProperty { get; } = 0;
```

or assign value in a constructor

```
  public MyClass() {
    MyProperty = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int MyProperty { get; }
```

is illegal.

you could simply write

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
```

to archive that

Comment: It's now legal in C# 6.

Comment: I just added a question to his prior one in order to find out what version of C# the question is referred to.